# how to disable images in puppeteer sharp?

Tags: c#, puppeteer, webautomation, puppeteer-sharp

im using this code to disable images in the page loading, but doesn't work:

```
_page = await _browser.NewPageAsync();

await _page.SetRequestInterceptionAsync(true);

// disable images to download
_page.Request += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.Request.ResourceType == ResourceType.Image)
        e.Request.AbortAsync();
    else
        e.Request.ContinueAsync();
};
```

how can I do that?

Comment: I used that same code on a public site and it worked for me.

Comment: @hardkoded but what's wrong with my code?! the page completely loaded but the event not fired! could u please post a sample code?

Answer (score 5):

This code will load www.kayak.com with no images:

```
using (var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions { Headless = false }))
using (var page = await browser.NewPageAsync())
{
    await page.SetRequestInterceptionAsync(true);

    // disable images to download
    page.Request += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Request.ResourceType == ResourceType.Image)
            e.Request.AbortAsync();
        else
            e.Request.ContinueAsync();
    };
    await page.GoToAsync("https://www.kayak.com");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand!!! everything is the same but the images still loaded!!
I used it in Windows Form (.net framework 4.7)

the only difference is: 
`var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
            {
                Headless = false,
                ExecutablePath = @"c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
            });`

Comment: Try removing your ExecutablePath argument and call `await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision);` before. Maybe is your Chrome version

Comment: I have the exact same issue.  Same code but yet images are still downloaded.  Did you ever figure this out?